# Plot text or label subsript that includes a comma in R

Tags: r, plot, typesetting

I am trying to add a label in my R plot for a lag in a hierarchical model $y_{i,t}$. I have the subscript figured out,....

```
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.8,expression(italic(y[i])), cex=10)
text(0.5,0.2,expression(italic(y[i,t])), cex=10)
```

[image: r subscript]

... but when I introduce the comma nothing changes?... and yes, I need the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the comma in a string:

```
text(0.5,0.2,expression(italic(y[i*","*t])), cex=10)
```

Comment: nice, did not know about the *.